# how to set min height in semantic-ui react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, semantic-ui

i using the semantic-ui-react. I have a Container `main` which has an `Segment` inside for show page details. but this Segment's height is changing according content inside. i want to set an mix height to alway stay fixed size. here is my  code:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Container>
          <Header />
          <Segment />
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can set minHeight style/css on your component or any div inside :

```
<Segment style={{ minHeight: 15 }} />
```